# Python urllib.urlretrieve and user agent

Tags: python, html, xml, linux

I am retrieving an xml file from a network device.  It returns the file in a different format without html tags if I do not specify a user agent.

import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve (url, file_save_name)

How do I specify a user agent when retrieving?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could do.

```
import urllib

# User-Agents for multiple browsers and OS's
user_agents = [ 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11', 'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12', 'Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/1.2.9'

# Add user_agent as header argument.
urllib.urlretrieve (url, file_save_name, user_agent)
```